# Excel vba to solve vba error by "if error, then" rule

Tags: vba, excel, printing

First of all, thanks for all the answers I have gotten on my previous questions, you really helped me out. The excel has evolved and now I'm ready to open different excel sheets in the background and print out different sheets on different printers. However, I'm working on a network that changes it's settings (which appear to change randomly).

```
Sub Client_Overzetten()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
Workbooks.Open ("G:\Moe\WD\Planning&Control\Client.xlsm")
....etc...
```

However, if my colleague would try to open this file, he will get an error, as the same document has a different link (due to access restrictions).
His link is

```
G:\WD\Planning&Control\Client.xlsm")
```

Is there a formula to go to another location the moment it hits an error? Something like:

```
Sub Kids_II_Overzetten()
'

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'
Workbooks.Open ("G:\Moe\WD\Planning&Control\Client.xlsm")
If error, then 
Workbooks.Open ("G:\WD\Planning&Control\Client.xlsm")
```

I have the same problem with the serverports of the printer, these ports change randomly

```
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi07 op Ne07:"
```

However, the next day it can be the same, or can be a different port

```
ActivePrinter = "\\w8vvmprint01\Moecombi07 op Ne03:"
```

With the solving of the problem of my first question, can I answer my second question as well (on error, go to the next line)?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the network locations you'll need to use the UNC path which will not change rather than the mapped path which can change on different computers.

To find your UNC paths open a command prompt (Run - **cmd.exe**) and type in **net use**.

The resulting table will give the local and remote names of the drives- just replace your mapped (local) connection with the remote one.

For example, 
**G:\Moe\WD\Planning&Control\Client.xlsm**
may become
**\\MyServerName\Moe\WD\Planning&Control\Client.xlsm**

Edit - the server name can also be found on the file explorer - **windows key + E** to open.
It will appear in the folder name as **Moe on 'MyServerName' (G:)**

To only use the mapped locations you could try:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Dim sFileLocation As String

    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER

    sFileLocation = "S:\Bartrup-CookD_SomeLocation\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"

    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(sFileLocation)

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1004 'Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
            sFileLocation = "S:\Bartrup-CookD\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"
            Resume
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Test."
            Err.Clear
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select

End Sub
```

or ask the user to select the correct file:

```
Public Sub AskForFile()

    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim wrkBk As Workbook

    vFile = GetFile("S:\Bartrup-CookD\")
    If vFile <> "" Then
        Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
    End If

End Sub

Public Function GetFile(Optional startFolder As Variant = -1) As Variant
    Dim fle As FileDialog
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Set fle = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fle
        .Title = "Select a File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*", 1
        If startFolder = -1 Then
            .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        Else
            If Right(startFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
                .InitialFileName = startFolder & "\"
            Else
                .InitialFileName = startFolder
            End If
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        vItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = vItem
    Set fle = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: The problem is that this would still give me an error message, as the domain is either G:\Moe\WD\... or G:\WD\...
Fixing the static partition to a network reference will not solve this problem. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I've updated my answer allowing  you to use mapped locations or ask for a file location.